Invalid connection with Desktop Flow Connection
I have a power automate flow uses the Desktop flow connection to connect to power automate desktop and activate a flow there.
The flow has been working just fine for months now, but I have been getting this error recently after I edited my flow:
The caller object id is '6c8b61f6-1680-4166-9a13-bfb08a485417'. 
Connection '09c4b195c27c4a96bd22975d3f112c6b' to 'shared_uiflow' cannot be used to activate this flow, 
either because this is not a valid connection or because it is not a connection you have access permission 
for. Either replace the connection with a valid connection you can access or have the connection owner 
activate the flow, so the connection is shared with you in the context of this flow.

The flow is failing now on this connection, but I don't understand the error since I did not make any changes to the connection.
I am not the owner of the connection. Myself and another person have edited the flow, and the other person owns the Desktop Flow connection which I assume is a reason for the error.
Can someone provide some context to the error and why it might be occurring? Is there any way to get rid of the error without creating a whole new connection?
